# Can I make a 1:2 macro lens into 1:1 true macro using only bellows?

Tags: macro, magnification, bellows

I have a Tamron 90mm with a 1:2 magnification. If I use a bellows will that make it 1:1? I know I can buy an extension but I also what to know if I can get 1:1 magnification with only the bellows without the extension ring.

Comment: Just as a note - the 90mm macro lenses tend to be a bit on the heavy side.  The standards for bellows and the couplings for extension tubes (and even the camera body mount) may get a bit of excessive stress if you try to hang a heavy lens on them that far out from the camera body itself. If you do go with bellows, try to make sure you have one that has a tripod mount on the bellows (rather than trying to mount the camera on the tripod).

Comment: A side note, as you've probably noticed the original extension tube which makes this lens 1:1 is hard to get hold of. The 2x flat field teleconverter is easier to find and results in a very useful 180mm f5.6 1:1 macro lens which retains infinity focus.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a bellows set should be able to give you 1:1, unless it's too deep when collapsed. In that case, it's not that you can't get *up* to 1:1, but that you won't be able to get *down* to 1:1 with the lens nominally adjusted to infinity focus; your magnification will always be greater than 1:1. In both cases (the dedicated Adaptall extension tube and the bellows) you will lose actual infinity focus.